# Python forget and destroy frame not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program where I check if the user has an active network connection or not. If not, the program displays a frame that says to turn on the internet connection. The the program checks to see if the state has changed, if so, the login screen is shown. But I can't get rid of the `noNetworkConnectionScreen`.
The `loadFrame` is the frame that shows the 'splashscreen'.

```
class AppUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Redux")
        self.loadFrame = Frame(self)
        self.initLogin()

    def initLogin(self):
        internet_is_on = False
        #check 3 times to be sure
        for i in range(3):
            #check the internet connection by pinging to google (returns True or False)
            if db.internetOn():
                internet_is_on = True
        if internet_is_on:
            self.initLoginScreen()
        else:
            self.initLoadScreen()
            thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.checkNetwork)
            thread1.start()
```

I also tried `grid_forget`, which crashes:

```
def checkNetwork(self):
    internet_is_off = True
    while internet_is_off:
        if db.internetOn():
            internet_is_off = False
            self.loadFrame.pack_forget()
            self.loadFrame.destroy()
            self.initLoginScreen()
        else:
           time.sleep(2)
```

And here I initialize the loadscreen:

```
def initLoadScreen(self):
    self.loadFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(150,0))

    self.lblUser = Label(self.loadFrame, text="HI", font=('Arial', 60), foreground="#666666")
    self.lblUser.grid(row=0, column=0)

    self.canvas = Canvas(self.loadFrame, width = 121, height = 81)
    self.canvas.grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.loader = PhotoImage(file = 'loader.gif')
    self.canvas.create_image(121, 81, image = self.loader, anchor = NW)

    self.lblNetwork = Label(self.loadFrame, text="please make sure you have an active network connection", font=('Arial', 16), foreground="#666666")       
    self.lblNetwork.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

I can see that the letters from `lblNetwork` are cut off at the sides, but the frame doesn't disappear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroying a widget and/or "forgetting" it are the right ways to remove a widget from the screen. Almost certainly, the problem has to do with your use of threading. Tkinter isn't thread safe, and should only be used in one thread. If you create widgets in one thread, you shouldn't try to use them from any other thread. In this case you're trying to destroy a frame from a thread other than where it was created.

What you'll need to do is set up some sort of communication between the threads -- a queue or a shared (non-Tkinter) variable. Since you are simply checking a boolean flag, a simple shared variable will work. In your main program you can check for this variable using a simple `after`-based loop in your main thread:

```
def check_network(self):
    if the_network_is_down:
        <display a message>
    else:
        <remove the message>

    # check once a second
    self.after(1000, self.check_network)
```

Also, if you call `destroy` on a widget, there's no need to call `grid_forget` or `pack_forget` -- once the widget is destroyed there's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: I can't really get my head around this. Should I keep my thread in `initLogin()`? If I use an `after` based loop, where should I add a loop? Because it is not looping.

Comment: I tried removing another frame where no threading is involved, which is working. So it defintely has something to do with the threading.

Comment: @Barto: i had a typo in my answer which explains why it wasn't looping. I've fixed the error. Call the function once and it will loop forever.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that you have to force the screen refresh ?

pyGTK sometimes needs this (but are you using pyGTK ?) :

```
while gtk.events_pending(): #   this forces the refresh of the screen
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

Comment: No, I'm using tkinter. I looked for an update for tkinter, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: There is a Tk.update() and a Tk.update_idletasks(). Both will force the UI to be refreshed. Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use `Tk.update()` or `Tk.update_idletasks()`, the app crashes.